# Python cmd script hanging when trying to loop

Tags: python, batch-file, testing, cmd, automation

I'm trying to make a python script to run a batch file multiple times with different configurations one after the other. The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to find a wait for it to wait for the run to finish and then run another one, but the cmd hangs and doesn't let the second argument to be written in the cmd. It does not do that when just using the cmd to run the batch file manually. So don't really understand what the problem is. I'm really new to Python so suggestions how to make this script better is welcome:

```
import subprocess

# open commandline
subprocess.Popen([r"cmd"])

# Run every test 5 times.
# Wait for a single run to finish before running another one

for x in xrange(0, 5):
    subprocess.run(["batchfile.bat", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg"])
    subprocess.Popen.wait(timeout=None)

for x in xrange(0, 5):
    subprocess.run(["batchfile.bat", "arg", "arg", "arg", "arg"])
    subprocess.Popen.wait(timeout=None)
```

EDIT:
Changing subprocess.Popen() to subprocess.run() made the hanging of the cmd dissapear, so now I only have problem with the waiting for the process to finish to start again. Updated the code snippet.

Comment: If you put a reasonably long timeout in, does it work and you get the behaviour you are expecting from batchfile.bat?

Comment: Please put real data. Does your script waits for input ? Does it print something ?

Comment: I have tried using a timeout from 1 second to 2 minutes to see if it helps, no change in behaviour.

Comment: The data is arguments on what files to use in rendering, all build into the application the batch files runs. So it basically runs a scene that - depending on the arguments - lasts from 10 seconds to a minute. @cgte

Comment: What is do in those cases is this : run the command from console. copy paste with shell=True option for only one script and use check_call or check_output function. see if it works then use proper arguments like you do. Why did you use r'' ? If the process outputs something maybe you should read it. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module the documentation recommends you to use these helpers functions.